# Edge TPU Compiler

Tags: linux, deep-learning, tpu, google-coral

i try to install the Edge Compiler on my Raspberry pi 3 model b. After i install this: (from google)

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/coral-edgetpu.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install edgetpu-compiler.
```

I get this Error:

```
sudo apt-get install edgetpu-compiler
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package edgetpu-compiler
```

Comment: Please follow your link https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt ... and read "-arm64/Packages" https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/coral-edgetpu-stable/main/binary-arm64/Packages .... I.e. no `edgetpu-compiler` for arm64. https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/coral-edgetpu-stable/main shows edgetpu-compiler for *amd64 only*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `edgetpu-compiler` package is no longer available for arm platform as per [requirements](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/compiler/#system-requirements).

Comment: can you say an alternative way to use it ? I need to compile my tfile and use it for my raspberry pi 3 model b (tpu is plugged in)

Comment: Hey! We have older version of it here: https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/tree/master/compiler/aarch64
but it's aarch64, most RPI's OS will be armv7l, not sure if you can use this one or not :(
My recommendation is that you try compiling your model in a x86_64 machine

Comment: Normally, there is an edgetpu web compiler, i can not find this ...

Comment: ahh, we deprecated the web compiler a long time ago :(